# How to record the log in matlab when I debug?

Tags: debugging, matlab, logging

I want to record the log of my matlab code output. Because my matlab code is a little complex, I want to check whether my code is right or wrong through the log.

It may be the same as "log4j" in java.

I can't find the way to record the log in matlab. If anybody can give me some advices, I will be very appreciated.

Answer (score 5):

Do you mean the [DIARY](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/diary.html) command?

```
diary on
```

will log all the command window input and output to a log file.

Comment: As far as I know, DIARY is only record the command of command history. However, I want to record my customized "fprintf".

Comment: @Taylor: That's what `diary` does - it records more than the command history.

Comment: Thanks for your help. I find the usage of **diary** in  [HERE](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/newsreader/view_thread/243063). It really help me a lot.

Comment: @Taylor: You're welcome. If you found my answer helpful, please consider upvoting and/or accepting it.